# LispWorks PE (installation) on Ubuntu 14.10 (64bit)

Tags: software-installation, 14.10, gtk, gtk-2

I have **problem with personal edition installation and launch on UBUNTU 14.10** (64bit).
Thank you for your advice.

My installation steps:

1. Downloaded files from lispworks homepage: `lwlper-licence.sh`, `lwlper-install.sh`, `lwdoc61-x86-linux.tar.gz` and finally `lwper61-x86-linux.tar.gz` ... all files in one folder
2. set execute attribute on .sh both files
3. license agreement script: `sudo ./lwlper-licence.sh`
4. installation script: `sudo ./lwlper-install.sh`
   5.`sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev gtk+-2.0`
5. when i start installed app using command `/usr/local//usr/local/lib/LispWorksPersonal/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux --->` **causes following error**

```
LispWorks(R): The Common Lisp Programming Environment Personal Edition
Copyright (C) 1987-2012 LispWorks Ltd.  All rights reserved.
Version 6.1.1
Saved by LispWorks as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51
User jirka on vincent-pc
Error during GUI startup:
  Could not register handle for external module "-lgtk-x11-2.0":
 libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

DESCRIPTION: Output Backtrace 

IMPACT: Broken/Annoying/Data Loss/Missing Error/New Feature/Performance Loss

URGENCY: ASAP/Current Release/Next Release/Future Release/None

PRODUCT CONFIGURATION:
  LispWorks Personal Edition 6.1.1

Process name: /usr/bin/lispworks
   ID: 10940    Started at: 2015/02/20 18:33:45

Save history:
1: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base, at 03 Nov 2011 13:25
2: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken, at 03 Nov 2011 14:00
3: lispworks-6-1-1-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51
LispWorks 6.1.1 - Personal Edition

Loaded Modules: 

Public patches: 
Private patches:  CAPI-GTK-DESTROY-REPRESENTATION

Foreign modules:
  #
  #
  #
  #

Signal Handlers
2       SYSTEM::SIGINT-HANDLER
13      SYSTEM::THE-NULL-FUNCTION
17      SYSTEM::GET-CHILDREN-INF

HOST CONFIGURATION:

  vincent-pc (x86_64), Linux 3.16.0-23-generic
  Ubuntu 14.10 \n \l

LWSerialNumber: Unknown
Site: Unknown
GTK+ not loaded

Backtrace:
#

Call to (SUBFUNCTION 1 ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT) {offset 186}
  SYSTEM::C : #

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : T

Handler frame: NIL
Call to SIGNAL {offset 1446}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : #
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : NIL

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : NIL

Catch frame: CONDITIONS::SIGNAL-CATCH

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*BROKEN-ON-SIGNALS* : NIL

Call to CONDITIONS::CONDITIONS-ERROR {offset 430}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Call to ERROR {offset 67}
  SYSTEM::ESTRING : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  SYSTEM::EARGS   : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Binding frame:
  FLI::*DLOPEN-FLAGS* : T

Call to FLI::CONNECT-TO-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 319}
  FLI::MODULE : #
  TYPE        : :MANUAL
  FLI::ERRORP : T

Call to FLI::CREATE-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 275}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::FILENAME         : NIL
  FLI::MODULE           : #
  OPEN                  : T
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to FLI:REGISTER-MODULE {offset 146}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::REAL-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::FILE-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to LWGTK:INITIALIZE-GTK-LIBRARY {offset 999}

Call to CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::ENSURE-GTK-INITIALIZED {offset 21}

Call to (METHOD CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START ((EQL :GTK))) {offset 11}
  CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::LOOK-AND-FEEL : :DONT-KNOW

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (:GTK)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #

Call to CAPI-INTERNALS:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 60}
  CAPI::ARGS            : (:START-FUNCTIONS ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER))) :ENVIRONMENT :CAPI)
  CAPI::ENVIRONMENT     : :CAPI
  PACKAGE               : NIL
  CAPI::LIBRARY         : NIL
  CAPI::START-FUNCTIONS : ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::START-CAPI-ENVIRONMENT {offset 24}
  LISPWORKS-TOOLS::ARGS : NIL

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (# NIL)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #

Handler frame: ((ERROR . #))
Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 158}
  SYSTEM::ARGS          : NIL
  SYSTEM::OLD  {Closed} : #

Binding frame:
  MP:*INITIAL-PROCESSES* : (("The idle process" (:PRIORITY -536870912 :RESTART-ACTION :CONTINUE :INTERNAL-SERVER :IDLE) MP::PROCESS-IDLE-FUNCTION))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::I-RESTART-WITH-ENVIRONMENT-AUX {offset 210}
  ENVIRONMENT::TTY-LISTENER-P : NIL

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-HOOK {offset 96}
  FUNCTION : SYSTEM::%TOP-LEVEL

Restart frame: (SYSTEM::TOP-LEVEL)
Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . RESTART-CASE)
Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 1)
Catch frame: SYSTEM::EXIT-LISPWORKS
Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE {offset 421}
Catch frame: SYSTEM::START-UP
Catch frame: SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION
Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 57}
Call to SYSTEM::CALL-IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 12}
Catch frame: (NIL)

Call to SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION {offset 50}
  SYSTEM::GC-MESSAGES : :DONT-KNOW


SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION

 Generation 0:  Total Size 515K, Allocated 386K, Free 120K 
          Segment 20090128: Total Size 507K, Allocated 386K, Free 117K
                    minimum free space 64K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 21EDE100: Total Size 7K, Allocated 0K, Free 3K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =2
 Generation 1:  Total Size 308K, Allocated 110K, Free 189K 
          Segment 2070F0C0: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
          Segment 200540A8: Total Size 240K, Allocated 110K, Free 125K
                    minimum free space 0K, static
 Generation 2:  Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K 
          Segment 20F1C640: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 117K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
 Generation 3:  Total Size 30387K, Allocated 30247K, Free 128K 
          Segment 2010F0C0: Total Size 6144K, Allocated 6139K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20F2D6B8: Total Size 16066K, Allocated 15934K, Free 128K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20720138: Total Size 8177K, Allocated 8173K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10

Total Size 31616K, Allocated 30744K, Free 502K
```

Comment: **sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386** solves the problem :-)

Comment: @Mudit: please review my additional edits.

Comment: Jiří: Instead of putting a comment in here, could you please put that in the answer section?  If you found the solution yourself, you should also get the credit!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `libgtk2.0-0:i386` solves the problem, lispworks is old and not 64bit compilant, so it needs i386 version of gtk2 libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```